# Calculating coordinates of a point at a particular time

Tags: android, timestamp, coordinates

Is there any way to find out the coordinates at a particular time stamp, while drawing on android? I want to know the x and y coordinates after every 5 milliseconds while the user is drawing something on the screen.

Comment: y do you want it at every 5 milisec it will available when user touches the screen...

Comment: When i sign on the screen i want to take the coordinates of the various points at every 5 milliseconds so that i get fewer points. If i keep storing each and every point then i may get too many coordinates, which aren't needed for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Override `onTouchEvent` and save `x,y` coordinates got from `MotionEvent` object ,
read that variables every 5 milliseconds using a `TimerTask` and `Timer` class.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try this and come back to you.